# Execute cmd command after service starts on Windows

Tags: services, windows-server-2016

I've added Apache to Services and set its startup type to automatic. This makes sure the service starts every time computer is started.

I'd also like to execute a curl command (`curl somedomain.com`), but only after the Apache has started. The emphasis here is that it must happen after.

How can achieve this? I am only interested in startup event.

I am running windows server 2016

Comment: Run a script that executes curl and check the service state of the apache service?

Comment: @Seth Vice versa - check the state, and run curl if state is "running"... or check the state in a cycle until the service state is "running" (maybe with time/count limitation to avoid infinite checking while any problem occurs), than run curl.